# has_many :through without a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm looking at some sample Rails code that sets up a `User` model like this:

```
has_many :posts, :foreign_key => :author_id
has_many :comments, :foreign_key => :author_id
has_many :post_feedback, :through => :posts, :source => :comments
```

While I can get my head around what this is doing, I'm unable to find an example of this functionality in the Rails docs, which seem to indicate that a join table is always necessary for a `has_many :through` association.

Is there a rule of thumb I can apply to situations where a join table isn't needed?

Answer (score 1):

If you feel you don't need a join *model*, you can do this using [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association).  But you will still need a join table in the database.  There isn't any way around this, as this is the only way to model a many-to-many relationship with an RDBMS.

If you feel a join table isn't warranted, then you probably have a one-to-many or one-to-one relationship which can be configured using `belongs_to` and `has_one`, but this doesn't sound like your case.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't originally post enough code for proper context, but it turns out this is an example of `has_many :through, :source` being used to (in the words of the Rails docs ) "set up 'shortcuts' through nested has_many associations."

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :comments, :foreign_key => :post_id
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Comment", :foreign_key => "parent_comment_id"

  has_many :replies, :class_name => "Comment", :foreign_key => "parent_comment_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :foreign_key => :author_id
  has_many :comments, :foreign_key => :author_id
  has_many :post_feedback, :through => :posts, :source => :comments
end
```

`:post_feedback` is just a custom name for the nested association (`:comments` is already being used) and `:source` is making the actual association explicit. Now Rails will understand `User.post_feedback` and return all `Comment`s on a given `User`s `Post`s, including her own.